# Initialize common view in base Activity class

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-activity, polymorphism

I have a parent activity `NavigationActivity` and it does something like this:

```
public class NavigationActivity extends Activity {
    protected LinearLayout navigationBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        navigationBar = findViewById(R.id.navbar);
    }
}
```

It has one method that sets the visibility of `navigationBar`:

```
@Override
protected void setNavbarVisibility(int view) {
   if (this.navigationBar != null) {
       this.navigationBar.setVisibility(view);
   }
}
```

I have an activity `AdventureActivity` that extends `NavigationActivity`:

```
public class AdventureActivity extends NavigationActivity {
    EditText title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstancState);

        renderAdventureLayout();
    }

    public void renderAdventureLayout() {
        Handler h = new Handler();

        title.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(final View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            setNavbarVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, 200);
                } else {
                    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override 
                        public void run() {
                            setNavbarVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 200);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I didn't have to declare or initialize `navigationBar` in `AdventureActivity`, and it's already initially visible. However, the statement `setNavbarVisibility(View.GONE);` doesn't seem to work in `AdventureActivity` unless I also initialize `navigationBar` as it was initialized in `NavigationActivity` because according the debugger, `navigationBar` was null when it wasn't initialized in `AdventureActivity`. I find it redundant having to initialize `navigationBar` in both activities.

Comment: where are you calling setNavbarVisibility method in AdventureActivity?

Comment: I'm calling it inside an EditText setOnFocusChangeListener, and the listener is being called inside a public void method.

Comment: can you add the code of focuschangelistener?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed, kindly see my edit

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided a content view in either of your activities, which results `findViewById()` method to return `null`.

If you want to create such an activity hierarchy, that means, that `NavigationActivity` should have an abstract method, that subclasses should implement:

```
    public abstract class NavigationActivity extends Activity {
        ...

        @LayoutRes
        protected abstract int getLayoutId();
    }
```

Then `AdventureActivity` would become:

```
    public class AdventureActivity extends NavigationActivity {
        ...

        @Override
        @LayoutRes
        protected int getLayoutId() {
            return R.layout.some_activity;
        }
    }
```

Now in `NavigationActivity#onCreate()`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(getLayoutId());

        navigationBar = findViewById(R.id.navbar);
    }
```

This mandates each of subclasses to provide a layout, where exists a `LinearLayout` with id `navbar`, otherwise your `navigationBar` would end up being `null`.